# IIS randomly returns 413 Request Entity Too Large when uploading large files and using TLS

Tags: ssl, iis, https, upload

I have an ISAPI application running on IIS, which is meant to support uploads of files of any size. On one server, uploads seemingly randomly fail with `413 Request Entity Too Large` or time out when using HTTPS, and the only remedy seems to be setting `uploadReadAheadSize` to a value larger than the uploaded file. This would, however, limit the size of uploaded files to 2GB (the maximum value of `uploadReadAheadSize`), which is unacceptable.

- Windows Server 2012 (and corresponding IIS version)
- **Server does NOT require client certificates** (but client was probably - and unexpectedly - sending them?!)
- The problem does not occur on any other servers (and there are lots of them) where the same application is installed, and where `uploadReadAheadSize` is set to the default (49152 bytes).
- The error is returned by IIS, and there is no WAF or similar intermediate component involved.
- The error occurs when sending from any host, including from the server host itself.
- The error occurs when uploading with a browser client as well as a thick client (a native Windows application).
- Shortening the request body actually does prevent the error from occurring.
- The identical request can fail or succeed (e.g., when replayed with Fiddler)

What could possibly be causing this, and how should I go about debugging this?

(NOTE: I have seen several similar questions on StackOverflow and here, but in those scenarios, either client certificates are meant to be used, or the application is based on WCF - which ours isn't - or the problem was not independent of `uploadReadAheadSize` or TLS)

Also, what is a good source for understanding what `uploadReadAheadSize` actually does and what is happening "under the hood"? Microsoft's official documentation is rather sparse.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing a similar problem. I am using client certs and I have set uploadReadAheadSize to 250m, but I'm still getting 413's on a 50k upload.

Comment: @jazzdev Nope. The problem mysteriously disappeared, but I believe the root cause was that the client sent a client cert, which it wasn't supposed to do in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got a similar error on IIS Express with Visual Studio 2017 and it actually was `uploadReadAheadSize`.

Error:

> HTTP Error 413.0 - Request Entity Too Large
>
> The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> - The Web server is refusing to service the request because the request
>     entity is too large.
> - The Web server cannot service the request because it is trying to
>     negotiate a client certificate but the request entity is too large.
> - The request URL or the physical mapping to the URL (i.e., the physical
>     file system path to the URL's content) is too long.
>
> Things you can try:
>
> - Verify that the request is valid.
> - If using client certificates, try:
>
>   - Increasing system.webServer/serverRuntime@uploadReadAheadSize
>   - Configure your SSL endpoint to negotiate client certificates as part
>       of the initial SSL handshake. (netsh http add sslcert ...
>       clientcertnegotiation=enable) .vs\config\applicationhost.config

Added solution here but the same principal can be used for a real IIS as well. Edit `\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`. Switch `serverRuntime` from `Deny` to `Allow` like this:

```
<section name="serverRuntime" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Then edit `Web.config` with the following values:

```
<system.webServer>
  <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="10485760" />
...
```

Comment: ... but were you using client certificates?

Comment: Yes but not required, `sslFlags` set to `SslNegotiateCert`.